# EF calls and returns from stored procedure fast but then converting it to list takes 20 seconds for 1000 records

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am debugging a piece of code which is using EF as ORM. Now, I am seeing somewhat interesting behavior from the application:

This is the code where I'm calling a stored procedure:

```
List<RequestListEntity> results = new List<RequestListEntity>();
var temp = System.Data.Object.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<T>("storedProcedure", param);

foreach (var item in temp)
{
    results.Add(item);
}
```

Observations:

1. When I run the stored procedure on the server, it is very fast. It has joins with tables, but it returns 1000 records within a second
2. When I call the stored procedure from C# using the code shown above, it also returns within a second and returns `objectResult<T>` with a total of 1000 entries.
3. Now when I try to iterate through the result **OR** try to convert the result to a List, it is hell of a lot slower.

Now this raises a lot of questions:

1. If it returning from DB so fast then why mere conversion of 1000 records is taking so much time? Or may be it is still going back to DB for conversion?
2. Is there anything I can do to make it fast? When it calls the function, it returns very fast.

Comment: Why not include your code for iterating through the result since you already mentioned that it was the slow part? Also, why are you fetching 1000 records? What will these records be used for? Lastly, how long is "hell lot of slow"?

Comment: Please show the code you use to populate the list? I'm guessing you aren't using a DataReader?

Comment: Can this be answered without further detail? Perhaps when iterating, further queries are needed, and with 10+ joins, that's a lot of time!

Comment: You'll need to supply some code that replicates the issue to get an answer

Comment: I updated the question with some more details and code but basically I am using EF's ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction to call the stored procedure and it returns ObjectResult<T>.

Comment: @jerrmy: no datareader. Directly EF to objectResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance issue is because of lazy loading and object tracking. when this method called result maps to an entity type, two things happen that don't happen when context.Database.SqlQuery is executed :

- The entities are tracked by the context's change tracker.
- The entities perform lazy loading.